# I how to display grid based on condition with checked selected (tick mark)

Tags: json, angularjs, checkbox, drop-down-menu, ng-grid

In html page i am displaying the drop down ,the item in the drop down are dynamic ,and below the drop down displaying the ng-grid data with check boxes these are also dynamic ,the dynamic drop down has the j son data as

```
[
  {
    "c": "D",
    "l": 1,
    "cId": 1
  },
  {
    "c": "J",
    "l": 2,
    "cId": 3
  },
  {
    "c": "G",
    "l": 3,
    "cId": 1
  }
]
```

In drop down i have displayed only property `"c"` value .
The dynamic grid had dynamic j son data as

```
 [
  {
    "c": "U t",
    "cC": "Ut",
    "cId": 1
  },
  {
    "c": "Ca",
    "cC": "CA",
    "cId": 2
  },
  {
    "c": "U i",
    "cC": "MN",
    "cId": 3
  }
{
    "c": "U i",
    "cC": "MN",
    "cId": 4
  }
{
    "c": "U p",
    "cC": "Mz",
    "cId": 5
  }
{
    "c": "U r",
    "cC": "Mc",
    "cId": 6
  }
{
    "c": "U h",
    "cC": "Mj",
    "cId": 7
  }




]
```

In grid i am showing only property of vlaue `"c":` 
If i select  `"c": "J"` in drop down then if the  `"cId": 3` matched with cid of

```
"c": "U i",
"cC": "MN",
 "cId": 3
```

whose data in grid then display that grid with check box selected with thick select mark ,and also if the unselected items in the drop down  `cId'`s are match with grid then display the grid with check box selected with light select mark .

After submit the button below the grid then display the only thick selected items of property value `"c":`

any thoughts on how to do this and/or a code plunkers  would be greatly appreciate. Thanks!

[image: LIght tick mark for unselected drop down id's match with grid ids]

[image: Item 1 selected result]

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xNb6J/8/ is working plunker which is suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

so you need to specify primaryKey field in gridOptions...

```
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, id: 101},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, id: 102},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27, id: 103},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29, id: 104},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34, id: 105}];
$scope.gridOptions ={
    data: 'myData',
    primaryKey: 'id'
}
```

Comment: I am new to Angularjs could you share your plunker code

Comment: please setup the plunker and i would do the appropriate changes

Comment: @sylwester could you guide me to solve the problem .

Comment: @user3812457 can you please have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/2dvPN/ before I add answer as I'm not 100% sure if is that what you wanted

Comment: thank you @sylwester ,but on loading it self item1 is selcted in drop down list ,so in grid whose id equal with item1 id have to tick or selcted (checked),could you change the jsfiddle .

Comment: @user3812457 that is gona cost you loooots upvotes:) please see here http://jsfiddle.net/w5B6A/

Comment: I am ready to accept the your answer with your guide lines ,could you notice the problem ,it is still not solved ,If Item 1 is selected then it is checked ok,but where as the Item 2 and Item 3 Id's are matched with Tiancum and Jacob Id's so along with Item 1 checked i have to show Tiancum and Jacob light mark tick mark or image uploaded in the question ,could you change your jsfiddle please

Comment: @user3812457 I'm confused now. When you change drop box do you want add item in ng-grid to be added to selection instead of completely changing selection or what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58235/discussion-between-user3812457-and-sylwester).

Comment: It is ok,but when Moroni id is changed to 5 in grid ,the id 5 is not in drop down so we have to show empty check box ,presently we are showing light tick mark instead of empty check box .

Comment: @sylwester just now i added the empty checkbox image.