# How can i compare the two objectes data in angularjs

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, foreach

I have two json objects in controller ,how can i match the id of first object with second json object id in angularjs 
 first json:

```
$scope.fetchAllCenters= [
        {
            "sid": 1,
            "group": "Group 1",
            "name": "Item 1"
        },
        {
            "sid": 2,
            "group": "Group 1",
            "name": "Item 2"
         },
        { "sid":3,
         "group":"Group2",
         "name":"Item 3"
        },


    ];
```

second json data:

```
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", id: 1},
                     {name: "Tiancum", id: 2},
                     {name: "Jacob", id: 3},
                     {name: "Nephi", id: 4},
                     {name: "Enos", id: 5}];
```

how can i compare `sid` of first with object data is matched with `id`of second object data in angularjs

Comment: please give solution ,no need to down vote with out answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($scope.fetchAllCenters[0].sid === $scope.myData[1].id) 
{
alert("sid of first fetchAllCenters is equat to id of myData ");
}
```

Comment: fetchAllCenters is in dropdown list so ,its value is changed based on drop down list selection ,i want dynamically comparison ,@sylwester could you answer in this situation

Comment: @user3812457 can you please post your html code for drop down ?

Comment: my actual  question is here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991240/i-how-to-display-grid-based-on-conditin-with-checked-selected-tick-mark/24991382?noredirect=1#comment38854305_24991382